# Operator Overloading in C++

Tags: c++, g++, operator-overloading

http://pastebin.com/Y7SXnrqr

This is a component of a larger OpenGL project. It defines a three-dimensional vector structure for use in doing some of the physics and graphics in said program. Apparently, my professor can get this to compile problem-free in Visual Studio, but when I try to compile it in any g++-based system it generates errors. These errors are as follows:

```
/Point3f.h:67: error: no match for 'operator*=' in '((const Vector3f&)((const Vector3f*)v1)) *= scale'
/Point3f.h:77: error: no match for 'operator+=' in '((const Vector3f&)((const Vector3f*)v1)) += v2'
/Point3f.h:82: error: no match for 'operator-=' in '((const Vector3f&)((const Vector3f*)v1)) -= v2'
```

I understand that lines 40-63 are overloading the *=, +=, and -= operators. What I'm confused about is why Visual Studio lets this compile and G++ wont. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
57:  friend Vector3f& operator *= (Vector3f& v1, float scale)
67:  return Vector3f(v1) *= scale;
```

You can't bind a temporary (in line 67) to a non-const ref (in line 57).

For each operator, write them as:

```
struct Vector3f {
    // ...
    Vector3f& operator*=(float scale) {
        // ...
        return *this;
    }
    friend Vector3f operator*(Vector3f v, float scale) {
        return v *= scale;
    }
    friend Vector3f operator*(float scale, Vector3f v) {
        return v *= scale;
    }
```

Comment: This is definitely the problem.  Microsoft's choice not to follow the standard on this causes SO much trouble.  Thankfully the fix is easy, just change the temporary into a local variable, e.g. `friend const Vector3f operator * (const Vector3f& v1, float scale)
   {  Vector3f result(v1);
      return result *= scale;
   }`

Comment: Or use pass-by-value, even better.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: [Definitely better.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) But don't return a const by value, as then you can't use move semantics (T&& doesn't bind to a const T r-value).

Answer (score 0):

Because the first operands of the overloaded functions aren't const. But they shouldn't be (in fact, can't be).

<s>But you don't have the copy ctor that the non-assignment operators use. Try adding the copy ctor.</s>

```
 Vector3f(const Vector3f& rhs):X(rhs.X), Y(rhs.Y), Z(rhs.Z){}
```

On edit: or maybe I'm completely off base. :)

And why are the op= operators written as friends? They don't need to be, as they aren't symmetric.

Comment: Thomas is right, the problem is binding temporaries to non-const pass-by-ref parameters.  Copy constructors have nothing to do with this (and the compiler generated a perfectly good one automatically).

Comment: You're right, I'm wrong, thanks for the correction. Edited answer to add strikeout.